# Why Can Wide & Deep Neural Net Work with Non-Normalized Data?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

My understanding is that inputs to neural networks should be normalized to zero-mean-unit-variant or binary. My own experiment also found that non-normalized network would lead to unstable learning. But [the tensorflow Wide and Deep Network example](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/wide_and_deep) uses non-normalized numeric features such as "age" and "capital_gain" directly. This type of network is not really different from typical fully connected DNN that much. Why does it work with non-normalized numeric data while other DNNs need normalized data? What other types of neural nets can work with non-normalized data?

```
# Continuous columns
age = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('age')
education_num = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('education_num')
capital_gain = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('capital_gain')
capital_loss = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('capital_loss')
...
deep_columns = [
    age,
    education_num,
    capital_gain,
    capital_loss,
    hours_per_week,
    ...
]
```